# Google Script: How run function ShowModalDialog with trigger?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Situacion:**

I have the following code, this funtion need to be check every 5 min the Column (H) and if the cell value is "CALL" show the dialog.

Now, if  i run the funtion from google script click on play the funtion run very well... but when I set up this funtion to run bases on time every 5 min didn't run.

```
function alertDialog() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById('URL ID');
  var Support = s.getSheetByName("Shift").activate();
  var lastrow = Support.getLastRow();

  var data1 = Support.getRange(3, 1, lastrow).getValues(); // Ticket# Column (A)
  var data3 = Support.getRange(3, 8, lastrow).getValues(); // Status Call Column (H)

  ///////////////////// CALL //////////////////////////

  var report = " "
  var callTable ="";
  for(var i in data3){
    if(data3[i]=='Call') { callTable += "<tr><td style='color:blue;padding:5px'>" +data1[i]+"</a>" 
                                      + "</td><td style='background-color:red;color:white;padding:5px'; align='center'><b>" + data3[i] + "</b>"
                                      + "</td></tr>";

   report ="<b>Pendig Call:</b><br><br><table style='border-collapse:collapse;'border = 1 cellpadding = 5; align='center'><tr><th style='background-color:black;color:white'>Ticket#</th><th style='background-color:black;color:white'>Status Call</th></tr>"+callTable+"</table><br><audio autoplay><source src='http://soundbible.com/mp3/sms-alert-1-daniel_simon.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>";



var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(report)
     .setWidth(400)
     .setHeight(450);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Ticket Pending Call');
    }

  else return; // If not true
  }
}
```

I will appreaciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your execution transcript, I get the error:

**Execution failed: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.**

So it looks like you can't call showModalDialog on time based triggers (although I'm not sure why you would want to)

**EDIT**

From your comments, use a try/catch block

```
function alertDialog() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById('URL ID');
  var Support = s.getSheetByName("Shift")
  var lastrow = Support.getLastRow();

  var data1 = Support.getRange(3, 1, lastrow).getValues(); // Ticket# Column (A)
  var data3 = Support.getRange(3, 8, lastrow).getValues(); // Status Call Column (H)

  ///////////////////// CALL //////////////////////////

  var report = " "
  var callTable ="";
   Logger.log('ran');

   try{
  for(var i in data3){
    if(data3[i]=='Call') { callTable += "<tr><td style='color:blue;padding:5px'>" +data1[i]+"</a>" 
                                      + "</td><td style='background-color:red;color:white;padding:5px'; align='center'><b>" + data3[i] + "</b>"
                                      + "</td></tr>";

   report ="<b>Pendig Call:</b><br><br><table style='border-collapse:collapse;'border = 1 cellpadding = 5; align='center'><tr><th style='background-color:black;color:white'>Ticket#</th><th style='background-color:black;color:white'>Status Call</th></tr>"+callTable+"</table><br><audio autoplay><source src='http://soundbible.com/mp3/sms-alert-1-daniel_simon.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>";


var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(report)
     .setWidth(400)
     .setHeight(450);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Ticket Pending Call');

    }

  else return; // If not true
  }
       } catch (e) { Logger.log(e)}

}
```

Comment: You get this error when you try to run this with trigger funtion, right? because if I run the funtion from script console the funtion run without any problem...
If I call the funtion from a menu, the same the funtion work... but didn't work from trigger. Why i Need that? The column H have a funtion for SLA, when the ticket need to be updated the cell change to Call... But I need a way to advice the user in a pop with the ticket needed to update... Because the system only allow 50 email per day I can set it by email alert.

Comment: Also other person provide a solution using sidebar, but the problem the siderbar need to open always for check the cell... 

I'm also trying to make the sound heard even if the active tab of the browser is not spreadsheet, that is, if I'm looking at another page, the sound does not come until I stand on the flap where I have the sheet.

Comment: a time based trigger will run even when spreadsheet is not being used so opening a UI when there is no user doesn't really make sense.  Maybe you can clarify?

Comment: That exist any way that the Ui only run when the spreadsheet is open in any user? The alert should be work when users are using it.

Comment: For example... I need a alert to advice a any user who have this spreadhseet open said ""Check the ticket# xxxx for Call".. If any user are logged to spreadsheet the system not alert.